# Converting number to ascii in 8086

Tags: assembly, ascii, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

in 8086(tasm) I trying to print out number to the screen. The below code works for most number but fails for 15876. **My question is how would repeatedly divide 16876 and get its digits as reminder? or is there a better to print 15876?**

Thank You.

```
    lea si,answerst         ;holds output
    add si,5                ;max length of ans

    ;add a $ at the end
    mov bh,24h      
    mov [si],bh
    dec si        ;decrements si 

    mov bx,15876  ;the number to print
    mov ax,bx     ;put it in ax because div uses ax
    mov cx,10     ;10 is the dividend

spctostring:
    cmp al,0      ;if the quotient is zero you have reached the end of the num          
    je stringme   ;if you have reached the end of the num print it out

    div cl        ;divide by 10     
    mov bh,ah     ;put the reminder in bh
    mov ah,0      ;resets ah

    add bh,30h    ;add 30 hex to get ascii value
    mov [si],bh   ;place the char in the output string
    dec si        ;decrements si

    jmp spctostring

stringme:
;---------------Output-------------------
    mov ah,09h      ;print string cmd 
    lea dx,numone   ;string to print
    int 21h         ;print interrupt
```

Comment: Why does it fail with 15876?

Comment: @AdamLiss The quotient never become 0 and then it get stuck in the loop.

Comment: One reason this method doesn't work is that `div cl` will put a quotient in `al` and remainder in `ah`. That means your first divide will have a quotient larger than `al` will hold since `15876` divided by `10` has a quotient `1587` remainder `6`. You end up losing part of the quotient. You'll need to use the 16/32-bit form of `div`, puttig `15876` into `ax`, and zero into `dx`, then divided `dx:ax` by `10` with something like `div cx`.